# Selenium in python get the new tab page file(html)

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

That is the code I use

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.youku.com')
inputElem = driver.find_element_by_id('headq')
inputElem.send_keys('星岚摄影社')
inputElem.send_Keys(Keys.RETURN)
print(driver.page_source)
```

The last `print` command printed (http://www.youku.com)'s page file, but that is not the file I want.

After the command`inputElem.send_Keys(Keys.RETURN)` executed, Chrome will open a new tab. That is the page I want to get.

So the question is how can I get the page file I want.

Anyone can help me? thx in advance.

To alecxe

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.youku.com')
inputElem = driver.find_element_by_id('headq')
form = driver.find_element_by_id("qheader_search")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('target', '_self');", form)
inputElem.send_keys('星岚摄影社')
inputElem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
print(driver.page_source)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to find the appropriate `form` element and *reset the `target` attribute* so that when you submit the form, it would happen in the same browser tab:

```
form = driver.find_element_by_id("qheader_search")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('target', '_self');", form)
```

Also note the typo you have in the code: `send_Keys()` -> `send_keys()`.

Comment: Would you please tell me what is the meaning of the arguments in the second command. I'm not familiar with js...And, the code you offer didn't work

Comment: @戴志廉 could u show me what code do you have so far and elaborate more on "didn't work"? Thanks.

Comment: ok, i'm sorry about that, i post the code at the end of the question in the last editing.

Comment: @戴志廉 I just want to see how have you tried to apply the solution I've posted..could u show me that? Thanks!

Comment: @alece please check this page again and you will find the whole code. thx

Comment: @戴志廉 thanks. As you see, I'm suggesting to change the `target` attribute on a different element. I do it on a form, but you are doing it on the input element.

Comment: I check your answer again, as you see, the `inputElem` and the 'form' you mean are the same thing except name. So if I want to open the search result on same tab, what should I change the `target` attribute to?

Comment: @戴志廉 the difference you see is crucial. If you want the search to be performed in the same browser tab, you would have to set the `target` attribute to `_self` on the element with `id="qheader_search"`. Why don't you copy and paste my code and try? Thanks.

Comment: Oh! I misunderstand your meaning, so sorry about that, you ask me to alter the page file itself. I have tried your method and check the result on the html file using Chrome development tools, but the search result still open in the new tab. Have you tried the code yet?